# click button for image array list run

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have problem with my image array list code he crush down and I don't know what to do. I need you to help me find the problem and fix it. My problem:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String[] strArr = new String[array_image.size()];
    strArr = array_image.toArray(strArr);

    if (btnNext == v) {

        currentImage++;
        currentImage = currentImage % strArr .length;

        iv.setImageResource(strArr.length[currentImage]);

    } else if (btnBack == v) {
        currentImage--;
        currentImage = (currentImage + strArr .length) % strArr .length;

        iv.setImageResource(strArr[currentImage]);
    }
}
}
```

**Here is all the java code:**

```
package com.example.hanansanag.mytourneyccreator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ssh on 25/12/2016.
 */

public class Players extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    protected Button btnNext, btnBack;
    protected ImageView iv;
    protected List<List<Integer>> array_image = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    int currentImage = 0;



    // int[] pic = {R.drawable.bacelona, R.drawable.athlethiko, R.drawable.arsenak, R.drawable.chelsea,
    // R.drawable.dortmond, R.drawable.bayernunchen, R.drawable.intermilan, R.drawable.realmadrid,
    // R.drawable.ashkelon,R.drawable.city,R.drawable.juventus,R.drawable.psj,R.drawable.milan,R.drawable.leverpool,
    // R.drawable.macabiheifa, R.drawable.macabitelaviv, R.drawable.beitaryeroshlaim, R.drawable.apoelbersheva,};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.team_pic);
        ArrayList<Integer> array_image = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        array_image.add(R.drawable.bacelona);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.athlethiko);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.arsenak);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.chelsea);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.dortmond);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.city);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.bayernunchen);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.intermilan);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.psj);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.realmadrid);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.leverpool);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.milan);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.juventus);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.ashkelon);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.macabiheifa);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.macabitelaviv);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.beitaryeroshlaim);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.apoelbersheva);

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNextPic);
        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeckPic);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String[] strArr = new String[array_image.size()];
        strArr = array_image.toArray(strArr);

        if (btnNext == v) {

            currentImage++;
            currentImage = currentImage % strArr .length;

            iv.setImageResource(strArr.length[currentImage]);

        } else if (btnBack == v) {
            currentImage--;
            currentImage = (currentImage + strArr .length) % strArr .length;

            iv.setImageResource(strArr[currentImage]);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to post the issue you are having, this is not a fitting question.

Comment: @Orbit i put it in the answer down here look bro https://s24.postimg.org/qqzwj5ix1/22334455.jpg

Comment: No, you need to update your post. This will likely be closed otherwise.

Comment: @Orbit ok ty i ediit i add the pic with the error ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
currentImage = (currentImage + strArr .length) % strArr .length;
iv.setImageResource(strArr[currentImage]);
```

By

```
iv.setImageResource(array_image.get(currentImage));
```

You can have a look at this
[Changing Imageview on button dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290500/changing-imageview-on-button-dynamically)

Comment: ty very much but loock the problem naw plz ?                                                 [![22334455.jpg](https://s24.postimg.org/qqzwj5ix1/22334455.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/pbybufhtt/)

Comment: ohh thats coz of your wrong declaration

Comment: replace protected List<List<Integer>> array_image = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(); by  ArrayList<Integer> array_image = new ArrayList<Integer>(); and remove the same declaration from onCreate()

Comment: Do tick it correct if it works..